# Does the no. of columns in where clause affect the speed of query in mysql

Tags: mysql, performance

I have searched everywhere but did not find any answer in this,

For example I have 8 columns in my where clause like this sample query:

```
select col1,col2,col3,col4,col5,col6,col7,col8 where col1 = 1 and col2 = 1 and col3 = 1 and col4 = 'sample' and col5 like '%sample%' and col6 = 1 and col7 like '%sample%'and col8 = '1'
```

I have tested this in my pc and the speed is just fine, But I do not know if this query will be fast in other pc that has lower specs, because the pc i'm using have high specs. I do not have other pc to test this kind of query.

Also some of the columns in my table are not indexed because its not applicable.

Thank you in advance

Comment: The more comparisons the engine needs to perform - the worse. "some of the columns in my table are not indexed" --- it doesn't matter, with `LIKE '%str%'` indices won't work anyway

Comment: @zerkms: Hi sir, can you explain more clearly? I'm a beginner to mysql. tnx

Comment: you asked if number of columns matters - I provided more general answer, that the more things you compare in `WHERE` - the worst

Comment: Ahh ok sir that is all I need to know, and also what i mean is that my columns that are using LIKE in where clause are the ones that is not indexed, thank you sir.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> There isnt a right or wrong number of columns to have in a table as the data that you are working with and the way you work with it should dictate your database design. (from: http://ask.sqlservercentral.com/questions/8461/will-number-of-columns-in-a-table-can-affect-perfo.html)

Some more performance related info regarding the where clause: http://use-the-index-luke.com/sql/where-clause

Comment: ahh ok sir, thanks for this brilliant information, Helps me a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Of course it is bound to effect performance to some extent - you are asking the database to do more work.

To help the query out make sure you have an appropriate [composite](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/multiple-column-indexes.html) index. Put the ones that are equal are the start and the like ones (but do not bother with like '%dffd') at the end i.e.

```
CREATE INDEX ON <table name>
(col1, col2, col3, col4, col6, col8)
```

Comment: OK sir this helps a lot too :)